# Adding page number to jQuery generated URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Google Instant style search script written in jQuery which queries a PHP file. &d=**PAGENUMBER** is the result page function on the PHP file and I want to make my script have this in the URL too. Currently when a user searches, a URL is created which is something like #search/**QUERY**/1/. How can I make the **/1/** my page number?

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").keyup(function(){
        var search=$(this).val();
        var query=encodeURIComponent(search);
        var yt_url='search.php?q='+query+'&category=web&d=1';
        window.location.hash='search/'+query+'/1/';
        document.title=$(this).val()+" - My Search Script";
        if(search==''){
            window.location.hash='';
            document.title='My Search Script';
        }
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:yt_url,
            dataType:"html",
            success:function(response){
                if(response !=""){
                $("#result").html(response);
                } else {
                $("#result").html("Your search did not return any results");
                }
            }
        });
    });
    if(window.location.hash.indexOf('#search/')==0){
        query=window.location.hash.replace('#search/', '').replace('/1/', '');
        $('#search').val(decodeURIComponent(query)).keyup();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var page_number = 1;
var yt_url='search.php?q='+query+'&category=web&d='+page_number;
window.location.hash='search/'+query+'/'+page_number;
```

Comment: Depends where `PAGENUMBER` is coming from. Updated answer